# Reusable DropDownChoice in Wicket Form

Tags: forms, wicket, panel, wicket-6, dropdownchoice

In my project I have more than 50 forms, and they are mostly simillar to each other and use the same `DropDownChoice` component. May I create separate `Panel`, where I define my `DropDownChoice`, and after that I will use that `Panel` in my another forms? Otherwise, how I can implement that situation?

**For example**

`form1` has the next fields:
**name**(`TextField`)
**surname**(`TextField`)
**city**(`DropDownChoice`)

`form2` has the next fields:
**Code**(`TextField`)
**Amount**(`TextField`)
**city**(again the same `DropDownChoice`)

I want to make beautiful solution of that approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is better to extend `DropDownChoice` with your predefined parameters, and not a `Panel` with real `DropDownChoice`.

There are at least two advantages of this approach:

1. You don't need to create separate markup file, as it comes with `Panel`-approach.
2. You could use `DropDownChoice` methods directly. Otherwise, you should forward such methods as `Panel`'s methods, or implement getter method for DDC.

---

So, it would be better to something like this:

```java
public class CityDropDownChoice extends DropDownChoice<City> // use your own generic
{

    /* define only one constructor, but you can implement another */
    public CityDropDownChoice ( final String id )
    {
        super ( id );

        init();
    }

    /* private method to construct ddc according to your will */
    private void init ()
    {        
        setChoices ( /* Your cities model or list of cities, fetched from somewhere */ );
        setChoiceRenderer ( /*  You can define default choice renderer */ );

        setOutputMarkupId ( true );

        /* maybe add some Ajax behaviors */
        add(new AjaxEventBehavior ("change")
        {
            @Override
            protected void onEvent ( final AjaxRequestTarget target )
            {
                onChange ( target );
            }
        });
    }

    /*in some forms you can override this method to do something
      when choice is changed*/
    protected void onChange ( final AjaxRequestTarget target )
    {
        // override to do something.
    }
}
```

And in your forms simply use:

```
Form form = ...;
form.add ( new CityDropDownChoice ( "cities" ) );
```

Think that this approach will suit your needs.

Comment: And to turn it around, if you **do** want special markup in your drop down, `Panel` is the way to go.